# Dynamic pages in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, dynamic, cakephp-1.3

So I've been creating my first client website with cakePHP, and have run into a problem.

I'm trying to create a system similar to WordPress where you can create new pages (simply title, slug and content), and they are served up to their slug address (i.e. About will be available at mysite.com/about).

I've created my own controller & model for 'Pages' (overwriting the core pages controller), and have set up simple functions (view, admin_add, admin_delete). My model is simple, just the $name so it can connect to the db.

I'm pretty sure my problem lies in config/routes.php. Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
App::import('model', 'Page');
$Page = new Page();
$pages = $Page->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'slug')));
Router::connect('/:pages', array('controller' => 'pages'), array('Page' => implode($pages, '|')));
```

It just doesn't work though. When I visit an page I have (i.e. mysite.com/newpage), it tells me the newpage controller can't be found.

PLEASE HELP! I'm on a tight deadline :)

Thanks,

~harley

Answer (score 4):

You need to extend the Class CakeRoute. Put your custom model code in there, and then pass that class name to your route definition in routes.php

routes.php would look something like this.

```
App::import('Lib', 'routes/MyCustomRoute');
Router::connect('/:page', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display'), array('routeClass' => 'MyCustomRoute'));
```

Then over in libs/routes/my_custom_route.php

```
class MyCustomRoute extends CakeRoute {
function parse($url) {
    $params = parent::parse($url);
    //import your model
    App::import('Model','Page');
    //create model object
    $Page = new Page();
    //find using $params['page'];
    if($Page->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('page.slug'=>$params['page'])))){
         //return $params if successfull match 
       return $params
    } else 
       return false;
    //return false to fall through to next route.
```

}

Comment: Thanks for answering bryan, I'm a bit stuck though. I got as far as this: http://pastebin.com/XDAEa1v6
But cannot really figure out how to get further. I don't fully understand how to ask for the matched $params.

Comment: @Harley Filled out example, you have to create model object and then use the $params in the conditions clause of your find.  Didn't test code so it might be buggy.  Made it editable so please fix it if I made a minor error.